# Embedding an image to a single Excel cell using Classic ASP - is such thing possible?

Tags: excel, asp-classic, export-to-excel, vba

**Short background** - I'm exporting an Excel file using Classic ASP, in which I generate a table which is originated at an MS SQL database.

One of the columns I retrieve holds paths to images I have on my server. I use the following code to define an "Excel-targeted" response:

```
Response.ContentType="Application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""Sales_Report-"& Month(Date())&"-"& Day(Date())&"-"& Year(Date()) &"-"& ".xls"""
```

**The problem** - I've been googling for a solution and came to realize (correct me if I'm wrong here) that embedding it as "contents" of a single page is impossible.

However, it is possible to either placing the image in one cell's remark (I'd like to avoid that), or alternatively just set the image as a cell's background.

**Important note** - my goal is to have the images sort and filter with the rest of the row they're located in. I did manage to place the images exactly where they should be to begin with, but they just float as regular images in the spreadsheet.
I'm using plain HTML elements and not XML - but an XML solution (if exists) would also be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: **Correction** - "of a single page" --> "of a single cell"

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after some research I've come to discover the research I was lacking to begin with. It obviously depends on the **MS Excel version** which eventually opens the generated file.

Generating XLS files with advanced cell settings is quite doable and intuitive when one acquires better understanding of the **XML structures** which help generating files through the code, with either Classic ASP & ASP.NET code behind.